# how to send parameters as input into mysql procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, functional-programming

I have atable called map_edge, in the map-edge table has the following records:

```
 childID  parentID
      3       21
      3       24
      3       26
      3       27
      3       30
```

I have created the following procedure in mysql :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE calculateID ( fix_val integer,position_id integer,child_id integer) 
BEGIN
DECLARE  calID integer;
set calID = fix_val + (position_id * 2 ) + child_id;
select calID;
END;
```

take a second row an example, I want to send as input to the procudure : fix_val = 100,position_id =2, child_id=2;
then `calculateID(100,2,3) = 107` `calculateID(100,3,3)= 109 and so on`

with this procedure, I want to modify map_edge table as:

```
childID  parentID
      3       21
      107     24
      109     26
      111     27
      113     30
```

could you help me , please ? can I solve the problem with function instead of procedure ? thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring variables in a stored procedure, you need to be careful to avoid conflicts with the names of columns.  One way is to use a prefix such as "p_" (for parameter), "v_" (for variable), or "in_" (for in parameter).

To write you code as an `update`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE calculateID (
    in_fixval integer,
    in_positionid integer,
    in_childid integer,
    in_parentid integer) 
BEGIN
    update map_edge
        set child_id = in_fix_val + (in_position_id * 2 ) + in_child_id
        where parent_id = in_parentid and child_id = in_childid;
END;
```

I don't see a need to declare `calID` in the code.  The value is only used once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, include the `UPDATE` statement inside the procedure only (OR) use a user defined scalar function and use the same in your UPDATE statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE calculateID ( fix_val integer,position_id integer,child_id integer, parentid integer) 
BEGIN
DECLARE  calID integer;
set calID = fix_val + (position_id * 2 ) + child_id;
update map_edge set child_id = calID
where parent_id = parentid and child_id = child_id;
END;
```